# iOS MessageUI.h not found

Tags: ios, sms, messageui

I want to use MFMessageComposeViewController to send an in-app SMS and I import the MessageUI frameworks in my project.
But when I use

```
#import "MessageUI.h"
```

Xcode told me that : MessageUI.h not found. I don't know why and how can I fix this?

Thank you very much.

[image: frameworks]

[image: The error]

Comment: #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> perhaps?

Comment: did you imprt message ui framwork?

Comment: clean and then build your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax:

```
#import "MessageUI.h"
```

would be used to import headers in your local project. To import system-type headers, use this syntax:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

When you use this syntax,the compilar knows where to look for the header in question.